# FHIR - XmlComposer and JsonComposer not found

Tags: hl7-fhir

I downloaded the Java build fhir-0.4.0-Java-0.9 today. I am wondering if anyone knows what happened to the XmlComposer and the JsonComposer that was there before. Has it been deprecated or where has it been moved to?

Comment: Where did you download from?

Answer (score 0):

I took over this project over this project from the previous owner. I am trying to do an upgrade from DSTU1 to the latest DSTU2 and ran into some build issue where these two classes are missing.